# Oracle 12c Grant Privileges Failing

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm currently trying to grant a couple of simple privileges to an Oracle database user.

I have tried the following queries:

```
grant all privileges to <username>

grant alter session to <username>
```

The second privilege is the one I actually need, but I decided simply to try and give the user all privileges to see if that would work. When I check the user's permissions using

```
select * from user_sys_privs;
```

everything seems to say NO.

I've even tried to grant the user dba privileges and that still fails. My end goal is to run scripts that require these permissions to be turned on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> everything seems to say NO

You're looking at the wrong thing. If the `user_sys_privs` view lists `ALTER SESSION`:

```
select * from user_sys_privs where privilege = 'ALTER SESSION';

USERNAME             PRIVILEGE     ADM COM
-------------------- ------------- --- ---
MY_USER              ALTER SESSION NO  NO
```

then the user **does** have that privilege.

The `NO` entries don't mean the privilege is not granted. The columns that is showing you are:

```
desc user_sys_privs

 Name                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
 USERNAME                                                                   VARCHAR2(128)
 PRIVILEGE                                                                  VARCHAR2(40)
 ADMIN_OPTION                                                               VARCHAR2(3)
 COMMON                                                                     VARCHAR2(3)
```

and [they are described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/USER_SYS_PRIVS.html):

> `ADMIN_OPTION` - Indicates whether the grant was with the `ADMIN` option (`YES`) or not (`NO`)
>
> `COMMON` - Indicates how the grant was made. Possible values:
>
> - `YES` if the privilege was granted commonly (`CONTAINER=ALL` was used)
> - `NO` if the privilege was granted locally (`CONTAINER=ALL` was not used)

As you didn't specify the admin option or any other modifiers, it's correct that both of those flags are set to `NO`.

---

What's probably confusing you is that all privileges are listed when you query for your user, *because* you did `grant all privileges to <username>`. You probably want to revoke all of those privileges, and only grant the specific ones the user actually needs. You'll then see a much shorter list when you query `user_sys_privs` - possibly only that single entry, depending on what else you need to retain for the user.

You might also want to consider using roles, though you sometimes need to have privileges granted directly anyway - if a stored procedure relies on them.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, that makes a lot of sense now. I'll take your advice and revoke all privileges and only grant the ones that I actually need.